# Matplotlib/Pandas line plot doesn't connect properly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts, data-visualization

I have the following function to create a line plot:

```
def plot_genres(genre_list, chart_title):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))

    plt.xticks(np.arange(1960, 2019, step = 10.0))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(3, 10, 0.2))

    plt.xlabel('Release Year', fontsize=20)
    plt.ylabel('Vote Average', fontsize=20)
    plt.title(chart_title, fontsize=20)

    for genre, sub_df in test_df.groupby(['genres']):
        if (genre in genre_list):
            random_color = [np.random.random_sample() for _ in range(3)]

            plt.plot('release_year', 
                'vote_average_mean', 
                     data = sub_df, 
                     marker = '', 
                     markerfacecolor = random_color, 
                     markersize = 5, 
                     color = random_color, 
                     linewidth = 0.5, 
                     label = genre)

    loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=1.0)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()
```

The `test_df` has columns `release_year` and `vote_average_mean`, which I want to be the x and y axis respectively.

I've configured it so that `genre_list` only has one genre in the list, so we would only see a trend line for one genre. Here's the chart that I get:

[image]

As you can see, there are multiple lines extending from a single plot, but I only want one line to appear for this single genre trend line. As far as I can see, there is only one point for each x-axis, so I'm not sure what the confusion is with the line plot.

Comment: Sort your points by X. Or use scatter plot.

Comment: @DYZ Thanks, I added this line `sub_df = sub_df.sort_values('release_year', ascending = False).reset_index(drop=True)`